# Why gcc preserves a callee save register while reading?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64

The simple function (x86-64, -O2):

```
__attribute__( (noinline,noclone,pure) )
uint foo() {
    register const uint* _reg asm ("r15");
    return *_reg;
}
```

The assembler output for this function:

```
push    r15    
mov     eax, [r15]    
pop     r15    
retn
```

Why unneeded pop/pushes instructions are inserted?

Comment: Note that what you're doing here is [explicitly unsupported according to GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables).

Comment: Additionally, this is one of the reasons inline asm is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and I haven't the faintest idea, but possibly the compiler only sees from your declaration that you are going to use `r15`, saves it at the function entry and restores it before function exit. The compiler doesn't see you are only reading the register.

The compiler would need to be extended with logic to track whether the register is being written to to decide whether the register must be saved or not, a logic that is not trivial, to safe only two instructions.